# Is Information_schema visible to everuser in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have created a user with this command

`CREATE USER 'bean'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
`GRANT ALL ON databaseA.* to 'bean'@'localhost';`

However, when I login as `bean` I am able to se `information_schema` and `test` databases. From my understanding, shouldn't `bean` only capable of seeing `databaseA`?

I also try to run `use information_schema` and apparently there is nothing stopping `bean` from doing so.

So, are information_schema and test accessible to every user?

FYI, the `root` user comes with these default tables: information_schema, mysql, test. And yes, `bean` cannot see mysql, which makes me think that maybe those table are accessible to every user.

Is there a way that I could do so that `bean` only capable of accessing `databaseA`, not others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `information_schema` is always accessible; you even cannot grant privileges to this database.

About the `test` database from the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-use.html) - *The test database often is available as a workspace for users to try things out.*

Comment: thanks alot. You saved me alot from being butchered by my own curiosity.

Comment: The answer is correct in terms of privileges, however there is a way to hide it from users, explained in the answer below:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';

Answer (score 8):

I had the same probIn the configuration file of phpMyAdmin (config.inc.php), you can add:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';`

this will hide that DB...

Comment: I wish i could rate two answers! Thanks for the information @Adam 1

Comment: The answer was from blindside, and you can still upvote the answer if it helped.